# How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a simple Chrome extension to add up the length of each video in a YouTube playlist and insert the total length in the page. I've succeeded at that, but my script only works after refreshing a page but not when the site is navigated. That's not very convenient though.

**Is it possible to detect page navigation on YouTube and insert HTML into the page** before it's rendered in the browser so that the added content is shown immediately without any delay and no page refresh is required?

Example link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_8APVyhfhpdgMJ3J80YQxWBMUhbwXw8B

P.S. My question is not the same as [Modify elements immediately after they are displayed (not after page completely loads) in greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413134) because I've tried MutationObserver and the problem is the same - a refresh is needed to show changes to the web page:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (var i=0; i<mutations.length; i++) {
        var mutationAddedNodes = mutations[i].addedNodes;
        for (var j=0; j<mutationAddedNodes.length; j++) {
            var node = mutationAddedNodes[j];
            if (node.classList && node.classList.contains("timestamp")) {
                var videoLength = node.firstElementChild.innerText;
                observer.disconnect();    

                var lengthNode = document.createElement("li");
                var lengthNodeText = document.createTextNode(videoLength);
                lengthNode.appendChild(lengthNodeText);
                document.getElementsByClassName("pl-header-details")[0].appendChild(lengthNode);

                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
observer.observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it doesn't work for my purpose. The part of the page I want to insert the combined video length into is already loaded by the time the timestamp for each video is loaded so I have the same problem, the page needs to be refreshed to show the injected HTML. Updated my question since it was marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Just tried that and no, that didn't fix it. A refresh is still required.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help so far. Here is the script, with the manifest at the bottom as well: http://pastie.org/private/yyc7piosnsna4yq7oymia

Answer (score 59, accepted):

YouTube site doesn't reload pages on navigation, it replaces the [history state](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

The extension's content scripts aren't reinjected when URL changes without a page being reloaded. Naturally when you reload a page manually the content script is executed.

There are several methods to detect page transitions on Youtube site:

- using a background page (or MV3 service worker) script: [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated), [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)
- using a content script and [`navigatesuccess` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/navigate_event) in modern Chrome
- **using a content script and site's own event for video navigation**

  So, to find it, let's run `getEventListeners(document)` in devtools console:

  [image]

  - **yt-navigate-start** is what we need in this case.
  - **yt-navigate-finish** may be better for other cases.

---

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "name": "YouTube Playlist Length",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": ".............",
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": [ "*://*.youtube.com/*" ],
      "js": [ "content.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
  }]
}
```

Note: the `matches` key encompasses the entire youtube.com domain so that the content script runs when the user first opens the home youtube page then navigates to a watch page.

**content.js**:

```
document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-start', process);
// Choose a different event depending on when you want to apply the change
// document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-finish', process);

if (document.body) process();
else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', process);
```

The `process` function will alter the page.
Note, the specified element classes and structure will change in the future.

```
function process() {
  if (!location.pathname.startsWith('/playlist')) {
    return;
  }
  var seconds = [].reduce.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName('timestamp'),
    function (sum, ts) {
      var minsec = ts.textContent.split(':');
      return sum + minsec[0] * 60 + minsec[1] * 1;
    },
    0,
  );
  if (!seconds) {
    console.warn('Got no timestamps. Empty playlist?');
    return;
  }
  var timeHMS = new Date(seconds * 1000).toUTCString().split(' ')[4]
    .replace(/^[0:]+/, ''); // trim leading zeroes
  document.querySelector('.pl-header-details')
    .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li>Length: ' + timeHMS + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: For reference, here is an example of the background script approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21071357/72321

Comment: This solution works fine, but unfortunately only for YouTube old design.

Comment: There's a new `yt-navigate-start` event on the site shown to some users. Also, I've slightly generalized the answer to explain how one can find the actual event.

Comment: Are you sure they do use `pushState` ? I had a really quick look a few days ago because of a question (I shall find it back to VTC as dupe of this one btw), but overwritting `history.pushState` and `history.replaceState`, in order to include an event emitter on these methods didn't worked at all, and this even if I did overwrote before the page had loaded.

Comment: @Kaiido, yes, they simply use the hack to restore the original API bindings via an iframe: https://puu.sh/wRIZg/6a3ad30828.png

Comment: Wow clever, I never saw (nor though of course) of such an hack. Do you know if this would even work if the overwritings were done on the History proto itself ?

Comment: Yes, this hack would work if you create a new iframe because it'll use the original browser bindings.

Comment: Great answer, any chance to use event listener approach for mobile version of YouTube (as it seems there are no beforementioned listeners available)?

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this allowed me to write a firefox addon to redirect from youtube shorts to the actual format in the correct youtube layout. Thanks!!

Answer (score 20):

2017 answer:

I use this for new Material Design version Youtube

```
body.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish", function(event) {
    // code here
});
```

and this for old Youtube

```
window.addEventListener("spfdone", function(e) {
    // code here
});
```

code come from 2 script I wrote call
"Youtube subtitle downloader" and "Youtube auto subtitle downloader".

both of them work, I tested.

if you are interested in my script and want know more detail:
https://github.com/1c7/Youtube-Auto-Subtitle-Download

Comment: Of note, this information _is_ covered by the existing answer (though it uses `yt-navigate-start`)

Comment: yes, this one didn't talk about principle but give out code right the way, I think this answer still have some value, so I would still keep this answer. :D thanks for mention it  @Xan

Comment: `yt-navigate-start` only occurs when the user tries to click a link (a navigation point). `start` and `finish` are not working as a pair. only `finish` is guaranteed in any kind of page navigation expect history change (`popstate`)