# How do I have my Chrome Extension run when my Youtube Comments are loaded or when my Messenger messages are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I want to change youtube comments containing a certain keyword to something else, but to do that, I have to detect their text. I'm using a chrome extension with a manifest as follows:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

and my content.js file is this:

`alert("Starting");`

Yet my alert goes off before the Youtube Comments or Messenger messages are loaded. How can I wait?

Comment: See also [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954) and [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077641/how-to-detect-page-navigation-on-youtube-and-modify-html-before-page-is-rendered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube comments and messenger messages are loaded Asynchronously, and your `content.js` runs at `document_end` i.e before these calls are preformed.

> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.

from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

you'll have to use some sort of listener, probably a `MutationObserver`, in YouTube this code should work:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('watch-discussion');
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
       console.log(mutation.type);
    });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
 observer.observe(target, config);
```

based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

by listening to childList mutations of the comments wrapper you'll be able to fire code every time comments are loaded Asynchronously into the page