# YouTube Userscript (TamperMonkey) to change the placeholder in Search

Tags: javascript, input, placeholder, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm writing a theme in userscript for TamperMonkey to theme YouTube, the problem i'm having is with changing the font color & the content of the placeholder "Search" in the search field.

What's the best way to do this in userscript?

Comment: And the problem is that it resets on navigation? If so, use [yt-navigate-start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952) to do it seamlessly with no flicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of the placeholder with CSS. Important is, that the value from @grant is `GM_addStyle` and not `none`.

Then you can add the styles like in the bottom example.

With `document.querySelector('input#search').placeholder = 'new placeholder text';` you can set a new text for the placeholder.

@wOxxOm thx for the hint with the youtube event. 
yt-navigate-start event is to early, but with the yt-navigate-finish event and a 200ms delay it works.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube Search
// @namespace     https://www.youtube.com
// @include     https://www.youtube.com/*
// @run-at document-end
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle(`
::placeholder {
color: red;
opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
color: red;
}
`);

(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.querySelector('input#search').placeholder = 'new placeholder text';

    document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-finish', () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('input#search').placeholder = 'new placeholder text';
        },200);
    });
})();
```

Comment: thank you, this did it! i tried to upvote but i dont have the reputation...