# greasemonkey script not works vs enhancer for youtube works

Tags: javascript, youtube, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

I'm a bit disturbed, when i tried this code in youtube website

```
var str = "My String",
el = document.querySelector("h1");
el.innerHTML = str;
```

It's work with "custom script" in the firefox's module "Enhancer for Youtube" but doesn't work when i put it in a greasemonkey's script.

Any idea where i'm wrong?

I've tried to add a windows.onload or document.onload before but nothing had worked.
I've add an alert before that work on both.

Comment: Use `yt-navigate-finish` event, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383788).

Comment: Thank you that work, that work with just a setTimeout function too!