# Chrome extension on Youtube Pages not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I just tried to create a simple extension for youtube that logs a message on the console on video pages and it does not work. I just do not get it, the same extension work in other pages...

content.js:

```
console.log("äquiii")
```

manifest.js:

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name": "Youtube Sentment Analysis",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/*"],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"

      }
  ]
}
```

Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: the same setup works for me. What's your directory structure? Do you have any errors in the console? Did you try running it with other extensions disabled?

Comment: Thanks Everyone. turns out my company was the one blocking me...