# Element added to the DOM but it is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

```
        console.log("hello");
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(data) {
            // do something with data
        });


        setTimeout(() => {
            let holder = document.getElementById("player-container").querySelector("#container").querySelector("#movie_player"); // get a reference to this element
            console.log(holder.offsetHeight);
            // add a button to the screen
            let activateButton = document.createElement("div");
            activateButton.id = "activate-ext";
            activateButton.addEventListener("click", displayUI);
            holder.appendChild(activateButton);
        }, 5 * 1000);
```

This is all the code I have in my extension's content script.

So, I am using `setTimeout` to wait for a min of 5 seconds(for the webpage to load) and then I query for `document.getElementById("player-container").querySelector("#container").querySelector("#movie_player")` element.

Most of the time it is working as expected. The webpage loads and then the UI is added to the DOM and is visible(of course after 5 seconds or so).

But every once in a while, I am seeing this odd behaviour.

1. I get a reference to the element I am querying for. I store that inside the `holder` variable.
2. the height is logged to the console
   3)UI element gets created
3. and it is added to the DOM.
   but for some reason, the element is not visible.

I can see the element in the code but it is not rendered on the screen.

When I checked, for some reason the injected CSS was not applied to the element.

***manifest.json***(content_scripts part)

```
"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://www.youtube.com/watch?*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: Since youtube is a SPA site your `matches` need to apply to the entire site: `"*://www.youtube.com/*"`