# Content Script not inserting into YouTube Results page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am trying to inject a content script into the results page of YouTube (after typing something in the search box on YouTube home page and clicking search). The script is not injecting.

I did some research and found that a possible reason is that the URL is being changed by history.push(). But after playing around with the methods, I am still not getting it to work. Every time, I have to refresh the results page for the script to inject.

Do any of you know what is going on?

Here is my code.

Manifest.json

"content_scripts": [

```
{
  "css": ["results.css"],
  "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/results*"],
  "js": ["content.js"]
},

{
  "css": ["home.css"],
  "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/"],
  "js": ["content.js"]
}
```

content.js:

```
history.replaceState(stateObj, '', "resultsSearched");
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
  console.log("printed?");
  chrome.extension.sendMessage("Rerun script");
};
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, callback) {
  if (message == "Rerun script") {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      sender.tab.id, {
      file: "results.js"
    }, function() {
      console.log("completed");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952). Don't forget to specify the entire site in `matches`.