# When is in description of the youtube video a word alert me

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

What i want to do:
Endlessly watching videos on Youtube and when is in description of the video word *Licence* alert me.

What i did:
I did exactly what is here written, but works sometimes and it is keep finding a word on previous page (but just on youtube).

```
//contentscript.js
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(                //wait for message from background.js
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
            if (request.message == "pageChange"){        //do when page changed 
                                                         //find word (copied)
                var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'Licence')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
                var node=xpathResult.singleNodeValue; 
                if (node==null){                         //text not found
                    sendResponse({message:true});
                }else{                                   //text found
                    sendResponse({message: false});
                } 
            }
        }
    );  

//background.js
    chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {      //wait for page to change (youtube is tricky enemy)
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {message: "pageChange"}, function(response) { //send message to contentscript.js and get response
                if (response.message == false){                 
                        alert("I found it!");
                    }else if(response.message == true){         
                        alert("I didnt found it...");
                    }
            });
        
    });

//manifest.json    
    {
        "manifest_version": 2,
    
        "name": "Send help",
        "version": "0.148",
        
        "permissions": [
            "tabs", 
            "webNavigation", 
            "storage",
            "activeTab"
        ],
    
        "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js":["contentscript.js"]
        }],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }        
    }
```

I also got idea to start finding a word when youtube video starts playing, but i didnt manage to do that. Youtube API is probably not suited for this.

Comment: The URL is changed before the page is updated. Use an alternative method: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952). See also [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Thank you for response, i tried the "alternative method, but its not working for me", so i am using a function to wait for description element to load Thats solved,
Next problem i have that content script wont load when next video is playing just when F5, so i tried chrome.tabs.executeScript, but then i need manifest v3 a totally redo it, which would took me days (yep, im idiot)- 
So, how to load content script when page changes? 
I have to use chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener, but i dont know how to load that stupid content.js

Comment: The example I linked explains why the things you observe happen, the solution works but you need to implement all parts of the solution and probably use `yt-navigate-finish` event.

Comment: I cant make it work, but i got i idea if event yt-navigate-finish even exists and it doesnt...
I fount it in document! YEY!

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer.

Comment: But im still stuck on the same thing. Script sending results from the previus page...

Comment: That's the job for MutationObserver or periodic polling in setInterval/setTimeout.

Comment: MutationObserver is not working for me, but Mutation Events did, but now i need to handle with "How to find a string in whatever is that output".

Comment: Mutation events is a bad solution since it slows down the entire page.

Comment: Mutation events is a bad solution - approved

Answer (score 0):

### Update 0.1

[That helped alot](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) - Mutation Observers didnt work for me, but Mutation Events did.

```
//content.js
document.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish",function (event){
  var insertedNodes = [];
  document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(e) {
    insertedNodes.push(e.target);
  }, false);
  console.log(insertedNodes);
})
```

Now i need to find a word in xy-tree with javascript, so i need to figure out new way.

### Update 0.2

#### The new (disgusting) way!

Page reloads until urls of new and previus reload are same. You ask why, right?
Its because im not able to find way to **check if in DOMNodeInserted is a word and not freeze browser.**

```
//content.js
document.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish",function (event){
  var newPage = location.href;
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
    if ((newPage) != result.key){
      chrome.storage.sync.set({key: newPage});
      console.log("Reloading page");
    }else{
      console.log("Dont need to be reloaded");
    }
  });
});
function finWord(){
    var source = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
    var found = source.search("Licence");
    if(found>-1){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }  
}
```

BUG: When reloading youtube video in playlist it changes index everytime it reloads.

*I managed to waste 100+ hours on that with a terrible result. Help is welcome.*