# Firefox extension DOM change weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

It's my first time trying to learn Firefox extension development. To get started, I'm trying to make a simple extension that alters some parts of the youtube.com homepage.

This is the `manifest.json`:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Better Youtube jk idk what I'm doing",
   "version": "1.0",

   "description": "Yep yep yippie",

   "content_scripts": [
       {
           "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
           "js": ["better_youtube.js"]
       }
   ]
}
```

and this is the `better_youtube.js` file:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("title style-scope ytd-guide-entry-renderer")[0].textContent = "something";
```

So, the element that this gets is the "home" link on the left side menu of the page. The reason I'm writing this post is that I'm getting an unusual behaviour:

- If I load the youtube.com page with the extension already enabled, nothing happens and the link's text does not change
- If, with youtube.com already loaded, I reload the script from the `about:debugging` page, it works

I tried running the change after 10 seconds (by passing the code to a `setTimeout(changeLabel, 10000)` call), but it kept showing this weird behaviour.

If it's of any use, I'm running Firefox 99.0.1

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
I changed the code to

```js
setTimeout(delayedUpdate, 10000);

function delayedUpdate(event)
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("title style-scope ytd-guide-entry-renderer")[0].innerHTML = "something";
}
```

and it now works, but I have to wait 10 seconds every time for it to load and it feels slow.
Through console logging I noticed that Firefox "thinks" the page is loaded when I still see parts of it missing, the issue might stem from that, but I don't know how to address it. Maybe my extension is conflicting with some script running on the youtube page?

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed most of the issues I had, the extension gets notified every time I navigate to a different section of the website (e.g.: home, shorts, trending...) but it doesn't work on the first time, since the `yt-navigate-finish` event is raised fires some ~500ms before the navigation bar appears. Is there a way that doesn't involve repeatedly comparing the HTMLElement against `undefined` to detect the first time it properly loads?

Comment: You can use MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), I found the solution: I can listen to some YouTube-specific events on `document` and I can use `MutationObserver` for when content on a page updates.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952).