# I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
const vidPlayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    console.log(typeof vidPlayer); // logs object
    }

});

observer.observe(vidPlayer, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Isn't my vidPlayer a node since it returns an object? when i log the vidPlayer it returns the element, as of

`<div class="multiple classes..." >(more nested elements..</div>`

I am building a google extension, so the manifest looks like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "title",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "50": "img.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://*.youtube.com/watch*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "index.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": "img.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: The element doesn't exist when the content script runs, it's created later. You should observe `document.body` and remove `watch` from `matches` because youtube is a SPA with fake URL navigation. See also [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: That worked like a charm. You're a great fellow. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your extension error on the extension management page.
You can see that line 5 of your JavaScript is unnecessary.

```js
const vidPlayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    console.log(typeof vidPlayer); // logs object
//  } This line is unnecessary.

});

observer.observe(vidPlayer, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: This is not what my code literally says, i was just showing part of my debugging process and attempting to not leave the code block empty. The inside did not seem important to post for this particular question.