# How to add button for youtube with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm developing chrome extension. I want to add button to youtube. But button is not showing. (It only appears for a very short time while the page is loading, then disappears immediately.)

Content.js

```
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Music Button";
btn.id = "btn-music";
btn.style.zIndex = "10";
document.body.appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById("title").insertBefore(btn, document.getElementById("title").children[0]);
```

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: It didn't work, can you give an example?

Comment: The answer I've linked shows such an example. You can adapt it to your needs (e.g. maybe use `yt-navigate-finish` event instead) and use devtools to debug the problems.

Comment: Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Comment: error for document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-start', process);

Comment: Read the answer completely, you'll see `function process` there.

Comment: I tried everything but it didn't work. Can you give an example? It could be an example of adding any button to the youtube page.