# How to access DOM element after async / defer JavaScript run on the ActiveTab?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension and want to inject DOM elements or modify some.

For that, I try with my `content.js` to wait for the DOM to load elements and then use it. However, the DOM element I'm targetting seems to be build after an Async/Await call.

How to access DOM element once Async/Await calls are finished ?

From my ***content.js*** :

```
window.document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  console.log(window.document.readyState); /* "complete" */
  if (window.document.readyState === "complete") {
    console.log(window.document.getElementById('chips')); /* null */
  }
}
```

The URL I'm targetting is a YouTube live  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxG3pdKvlIs&ab_channel=FRANCE24 (for instance). Running in the DevConsole : `window.document.getElementById('chips')` correctly log the element.

Comment: Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for changes to the parent element, then act accordingly when the new content has been added to the DOM.

Comment: See also [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MutationObserver` API to detect when the element is added to the DOM and then modify it.

Here's an example of how you can use `MutationObserver` to detect when an element with ID `chips` is added to the DOM:

```js
// Create a new MutationObserver
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    // Check if the element with ID 'chips' has been added to the DOM
    if (mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      const chipsElement = document.getElementById('chips');
      if (chipsElement) {
        // Modify the element here
        console.log(chipsElement);
        // Disconnect the observer once the element has been found
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    }
  });
});

// Start observing the document for changes
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

This code creates a new `MutationObserver` and starts observing the document for changes. When a change is detected, it checks if the element with ID `chips` has been added to the DOM. If it has, it modifies the element and disconnects the observer.

You can put this code in your `content.js` file to wait for the element to be added to the DOM and then modify it.