# Chrome extension manifest v3 content script not executed on href function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to make  a chrome extension working in Youtube pages. The main purpose is to inject a 'play all' button upon every visit to the main page of all YouTube channels.

I wrote URL matches on Youtube in the manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    ....
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["scripts/makeButton.js"],
            "matches": [
                "https://www.youtube.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the makeButton.js script is not executed after I click the channel name at video page (It appears to redirect to the main page of that channel)

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OjRClPzU6Y]

The source code reveals a reference to the channel handle through the 'href' attribute.

```html
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/@talksatgoogle" dir="auto">Talks at Google</a>
```

After clicking this hyperlink, URL changes but my content script is not executed at all. To make it work, how do I modify the manifest or js file?

P.S. There are manifest version 2 solutions that use background.js and addListener to chrome.tabs but I want manifest version 3 way to solve this problem.

Comment: This site is using SPA technology. You can use chrome.tabs.onUpdated in the background script or a simpler approach: [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)