# Tampermonkey script run before page load

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I need to hide a section from an html page:

```
<h1 data-ng-show="!menuPinned &amp;&amp; !isSaaS" class="logo floatLeft" aria-hidden="false"><span>XXX&nbsp;</span><span style="font-weight: bold;">XXX&nbsp;</span><span>XXXXX</span></h1>
```

The following code works fine in Chrome dev. tools

```
var ibmlogo = document.querySelectorAll('h1.logo.floatLeft');
ibmlogo[1].remove();
```

But when I load the page with the script active, the section (h1) won't disappear.
I believe this is because when the script runs, the DOM has not been completed loaded yet, hence the script fails to find the selector.

I have tried many different things (e.g. window.onLoad) but still my script is not effective. Last attempt (failed) is the following:

```
var logo = document.querySelectorAll('h1.logo.floatLeft');
logo.onload = function() {removeLogo()};

function removeLogo(){
    console.log("### logo array lenght: " + logo.length);
    logo[1].remove();
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't a user style (e.g. using  [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)) with `h1.logo.floatLeft { display: none; }` do the trick?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Required:**

- [@run-at: document-start](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) in userscript metablock.

  ```
  // ==UserScript==
  ..............
  // @run-at        document-start
  ..............
  // ==/UserScript==
  ```

Now with the above your options are:

1. Simply inject a style that hides the logo:

   ```
   (document.head || document.documentElement).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
       '<style>h1.logo.floatLeft { display: none!important; }</style>');
   ```
2. Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect and delete the element immediately after it's added into DOM.

   - [Modify elements immediately (not after page completely loads)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413134)
   - [How to change the HTML content as it's loading on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334319) ("rare elements" code)
   - [Performance of MutationObserver to detect nodes in entire DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39332340).

   ```
   new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
       // check at least two H1 exist using the extremely fast getElementsByTagName
       // which is faster than enumerating all the added nodes in mutations
       if (document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[1]) {
           var ibmlogo = document.querySelectorAll('h1.logo.floatLeft')[1];
           if (ibmlogo) {
               ibmlogo.remove();
               this.disconnect(); // disconnect the observer
           }
       }
   }).observe(document, {childList: true, subtree: true});
   // the above observes added/removed nodes on all descendants recursively
   ```

Comment: Thanks @woxxom, the first option does the trick even if I don't quite understand how. When the script run my element doesn't exist (I tested with document.querySelectorAll, so how can the insertAdjacentHTML inject something in a non existing node? And if it's create a node, when the page eventually loads, it shouldn't override my injected element?

Comment: Hi couldn't make he second option (much fancier) working, in your code I get a syntax error in the second to last line (can't understand why). I then tried the sample from mozilla web site and the code fails because the target is not an Node, and checking it, when I create the target the element doesn't exist (I even tried with 'html') and target is always null.
.
Cheers

Comment: 1. It's what CSS sheets are for 2. The code should work as-is, don't change `document` parameter in `observe`. Anyway, I'm not psychic, so I can't tell what happens in your browser

Comment: it is not clear. wher to put my scripts? after document-start of before?

Comment: After `// ==/UserScript==`, on a new line.

Comment: awesome. this allowed me to inject window.onbeforeprint function into gmail print view without needing to close & restart the print dialogue!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to modify some inline JSON. `MutationObserver` did not work but simply overriding `JSON.parse()` did the trick.

```
var oldJsonParse = JSON.parse;
JSON.parse = function(content) {
    if (content.includes("someProp")) {
        var jsonContent = oldJsonParse(content);
        jsonContent.someProp = 2;
        return jsonContent;
    } else {
        return oldJsonParse(content);
    }
}
```