# How to get over a blocked event?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an JavaScript app which needs to trigger `mousemove` event, and I am using tampermonkey to "embed" it on websites to test if it works on them. On one website, the `mousemove` event is simply blocked (I don't know why) and even `console.log` within this event doesn't show. It seems like this event has never triggered (the website ignores).

Is it possible to "override" events and block them? If so, how can I override this action and enable my specific `mousemove` event?

This script won't work:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("[HELLO] Is it moving?!");
}, false);
```

(the result will be... nothing. this won't be logged)

**Update** They set `window.onmousemove` as `null`. Is there any way to revert this?

Comment: also if you're running your code on random sites it is possible that for whatever reason the js on the site is removing event handlers on an interval or something causing your mouse move not to fire (first answer is much more likely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run your code before theirs, you can save the function

```js
window.onmousemove = function()  {
  console.log("moving",new Date())
};
window.myMove = window.onmousemove;
document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("click",function() {
  window.onmousemove=null
})

document.getElementById("y").addEventListener("click",function() {
  window.onmousemove=myMove;
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="x">Turn off mousemove</button>
<button type="button" id="y">Turn mousemove back on</button>
```

Comment: And if my code comes after, It means I can't return `window.onmousemove` to its original value?

Comment: This is the case. They turned `mousemove` to null. I've checked it in the console. How can I revert this? (If I can)

Comment: Only by injecting before them

Comment: Is it possible with tampermonkey?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39347807/295783

Answer (score 0):

If some other event handler called `stopPropagation()` on the event, it won't be propagated up to the `document` level during the "bubble" phase.

However, you can make your event handler be called sooner, by running it in the "capture" phase. Simply change the third argument from `false` to `true`. This will solve most issues, except if some other event handler on the `document` was added before yours, and calls `stopImmediatePropagation` on the event. But this is rare.

See [Bubbling and capturing explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_and_capturing_explained) for more background information.

Comment: I will try it out

Comment: It seems like changing the argument to `true` doesn't do anything